# Multiple table join with possible conditional matches

Tags: mysql

I have several tables that I combine in an application I'm creating in PHP that essentially creates a check list. I realize I could solve this problem using a conditional in PHP, but am curious if MySQL is capable of accomplishing this and if so, how? Specifically, I have four tables which are queried using the following statement:

```
SELECT 
cl_status.status, 
users.user_first, 
cl_status.date AS status_date, 
cl_status.id AS status_id, 
cl_status.criteria_id,
cl_criteria.id AS cid, 
cl_criteria.description AS description 

FROM cl_criteria 
LEFT JOIN cl_lists 
  ON cl_criteria.cl_id = cl_lists.id 
RIGHT JOIN cl_status 
  ON cl_criteria.id = cl_status.criteria_id 
LEFT JOIN users 
  ON cl_status.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE cl_lists.id = '1'

Table one - cl_lists:
+----+------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| id | title            | date       | comp_level | owner |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | Newcomer's guide | 1452473606 |          1 |     1 |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+-------+

 Table two - cl_assign:
+----+-------+-------+------------+
| id | cl_id | owner | date       |
+----+-------+-------+------------+
|  1 |     1 |     1 | 1455843514 |
+----+-------+-------+------------+

Table three - cl_status:
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+----------+
| id | criteria_id | user_id | description | date       | status | comments |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+----------+
|  2 |          66 |       1 |             |       NULL |      1 | NULL     |
| 15 |          65 |       1 |             | 1455842197 |      5 | NULL     |
| 16 |          67 |       1 |             | 1455842201 |      5 | NULL     |
| 17 |          68 |       1 |             | 1455842203 |      5 | NULL     |
| 18 |          69 |       1 |             | 1455842217 |      0 | NULL     |
| 19 |          70 |       1 |             | 1455842222 |      5 | NULL     |
| 20 |          72 |       1 |             | 1455842237 |      1 | NULL     |
| 21 |          71 |       1 |             | 1455842234 |      0 | NULL     |
| 22 |          73 |       1 |             | 1455842246 |      5 | NULL     |
| 23 |          76 |       1 |             | 1455842249 |      5 | NULL     |
| 24 |          77 |       1 |             | 1455842268 |      5 | NULL     |
| 25 |          78 |     152 |             | 1455854420 |      3 | NULL     |
| 26 |          81 |       1 |             | 1455843660 |      5 | NULL     |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+----------+

Table four - users:
+---------+------------+
| user_id | user_first |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | Mark       |
|       2 | Test       |
+---------+------------+
```

Ideally, I'd like the join to look like this:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
| status | user_first | status_date | status_id | criteria_id | cid  | description                 |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842197 |        15 |          65 |   65 | Tour of facility            |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842201 |        16 |          67 |   67 | Tax forms                   |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842203 |        17 |          68 |   68 | 2 forms of ID               |
|      0 | Mark       |  1455842217 |        18 |          69 |   69 | Benefits                    |   |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842246 |        22 |          73 |   73 | Intro to policies           |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842249 |        23 |          76 |   76 | Setup email account         |
|   NULL | NULL       |  NULL       |      NULL |          78 |   78 | Setup Computer account      |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

However, it looks like this:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
| status | user_first | status_date | status_id | criteria_id | cid  | description                 |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842197 |        15 |          65 |   65 | Tour of facility            |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842201 |        16 |          67 |   67 | Tax forms                   |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842203 |        17 |          68 |   68 | 2 forms of ID               |
|      0 | Mark       |  1455842217 |        18 |          69 |   69 | Benefits                    |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842246 |        22 |          73 |   73 | Intro to policies           |
|      5 | Mark       |  1455842249 |        23 |          76 |   76 | Setup email account         |
|      3 | Temp       |  1455854420 |        25 |          78 |   78 | Setup Computer account      |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Is there a way to apply the conditional before the join? Or another way to accomplish the result set that I want?

**EDIT**
This is a screenshot of what the application looks like:
[image: Application Screenshot]

The criteria table will include steps of every checklist I have. The list table is a list of the various checklists. The status table allows every user (such as Mark, or Test) to look at the same checklist and complete it as if it was a separate document. It also populates the date/time that the item was updated by that user.

Comment: Do you want a portion of the record to be `NULL` when the user status is `3`?

Comment: Users status doesn't matter. Essentially, I have a list of criteria being run for any user it is assigned to. If the user has done something with it, it'll either add or update in the status table. If they have never done anything, there won't be a record in status - that's when I want a null value.

Comment: Well for the record in your example which you want nulled out, there _is_ a record in the `status` table.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Through the joins, I want to load everything in the criteria table, regardless of whether a match exists in the status table for a given user. However, if there is a matching record in the status table that matches the user_id, I want the status information. If there is not a matching user_id in the status table, I want it to show nulls.

Comment: Using `LEFT` or `RIGHT` joins is the way to go, but your data and query is not clear to me.

Comment: Where is the `Temp` value for `user_first` coming from?  I don't see this anywhere in your sample data.

Comment: I directly manipulated the database for a non-matching result. It doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103915/discussion-between-thebarless-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `RIGHT JOIN` you have in your query is causing the records you want to appear to be filtered out.  Remember that `t1 RIGHT JOIN t2` is the same as `t2 LEFT JOIN t1`, meaning that `t1` will lose any record which does not appear in `t2`, with `t2` keeping all its records.  Try this:

```
SELECT cl_status.status, users.user_first, cl_status.date AS status_date,
       cl_status.id AS status_id, cl_status.criteria_id, cl_criteria.id AS cid,
       cl_criteria.description AS description 
FROM cl_criteria LEFT JOIN cl_lists 
    ON cl_criteria.cl_id = cl_lists.id 
LEFT JOIN cl_status 
    ON cl_criteria.id = cl_status.criteria_id 
LEFT JOIN users 
    ON cl_status.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE cl_lists.id = '1'
```